# Efficient network server design examples, written in C

Tags: c, linux, performance, multithreading, network-programming

I am interested in learning how to write extremely efficient network server software and I don't mind getting my hands dirty with pointers, sockets and threading. I'm talking a server being able to handle thousands of concurrent connections. There is not much processing for each client, but a little.

**Do you know of any code examples for really efficient network servers?**

Optionally points for small, well documented code that is cross-platform as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at [nginx](http://nginx.net/), [lighttpd](http://www.lighttpd.net) and [varnish](http://varnish.projects.linpro.no/) for some popular high performance http servers.

BTW, I am currently working on combining edge-triggered epoll with multithreading (plus user-level swapcontext-style threads/fibers) - see http://svn.cmeerw.net/src/nginetd/trunk/ for some work-in-progress code (although this one is written in C++).

Answer (score 5):

You'll find a lot of good references and discussion about building highly scalable network servers on Dan Kegel's [The C10K problem](http://www.kegel.com/c10k.html) page.

Comment: A list of open-source server implementations using the various described approaches can be found near the bottom of the page.

Comment: It's a good page, been there before. But I still feel that the example part of the page is lacking, mostly in edge-triggered solutions. Hence, the question :)

Answer (score 1):

This may not be exactly what you are looking for, but I briefly recall looking at Space Tyrant a few years back and thinking it sounded cool.

http://librenix.com/?inode=6240

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

Read this

http://www.evanmiller.org/lxr/http/source/

Answer (score 1):

an ldap-server handles lots of transactions per second

http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lightweight_Directory_Access_Protocol

Answer (score 1):

ACE is a wise choice.